Mouseleave event not getting called after dragging an item
I have this React code snippet that should also execute the code in useEffect:
    useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
        console.log("end");
      });
      document.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        console.log("hello");
      });
    }, []);

Why is it that after I drag an item, the mouseleave event is no longer being listened to?
     <div
        id="draggable"
        draggable
        onDragLeave={(event) => {
          console.log("mouseleave");
          event.preventDefault();
        }}
        onDragEnd={(event) => {
          console.log("onDragEnd");
          event.preventDefault();
        }}
      >
        Drag me!
      </div>

